# Changing Timestamp 'Created_at' value with Characters in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, timestamp, eloquent

I am trying to change 'created_at' value from '2015-03-26 08:43:04' to '2015-03-26T08:43:04Z', which is in an Eloquent object in `$result`.

```
foreach($results as $value){
            $stamp = str_replace(' ','T',$value->created_at).'Z';
            $value->created_at=$stamp;
             echo $value->created_at;
             }
```

This is the code I am using to do that, unfortunately I couldn't able to do that. It's not accepting timestamp with Characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your results using accessors and mutators. These are described at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Mutator helps you set the value by custom format and you can define the parser yourself. Similarly accessor enables you to change format of the date before being returned.

Comment: More specifically [Date Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#date-mutators)